# Swift picture metaData creation date

Tags: ios, swift, image

I am trying with Swift from iOS picture upload and get picture metaDate example creation date but I got not full information:

```
{
ColorModel = RGB;
Depth = 8;
Orientation = 1;
PixelHeight = 2080;
PixelWidth = 1170;
ProfileName = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1";
"{Exif}" =     {
    ColorSpace = 1;
    PixelXDimension = 1170;
    PixelYDimension = 2080;
};
"{JFIF}" =     {
    DensityUnit = 0;
    JFIFVersion =         (
        1,
        0,
        1
    );
    XDensity = 72;
    YDensity = 72;
};
"{TIFF}" =     {
    Orientation = 1;
};
```

}

My swift code:

```
        let imageData: Data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)!
        let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData as CFData, nil)!
        let metadata = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, nil)!
       
        print(metadata)
```

And my picture have creation date because I checked with another app's and I saw full metaData

Answer (score 0):

Below is a function I created in a playground when experimenting with image metadata, it uses a file from an URL but it should be useful for you if you use `CGImageSourceCreateWithData` instead

```
func createDate(for url: URL) -> String? {
    guard let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url as CFURL, nil),
          let properties = CGImageSourceCopyMetadataAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil) else {
        return nil
    }
    let datePath = "xmp:CreateDate" as CFString
    return CGImageMetadataCopyStringValueWithPath(properties, nil, datePath) as String?
}
```

Comment: it's really return image creation date? because it's look no and for me I get nil

Comment: For me it returns a date string when testing with a jpeg and a dng image file. What happens if you try with "exif:ColorSpace" since you have this in your sample data?

Comment: Yap, I got colorSpace value

Comment: Then the code works but you don't have the tag I used. Maybe try exif instead of xmp or DateTimeOriginal instead of CreateDate in the path string.