# Swift image i/o missing metaData

Tags: ios, swift

I am using image I/O. I want take all metaData include **kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeDigitized** and others.

But I get very little information:

```
ColorModel = RGB;
Depth = 8;
Orientation = 6;
PixelHeight = 3024;
PixelWidth = 4032;
ProfileName = "Display P3";
"{Exif}" =     {
    ColorSpace = 65535;
    PixelXDimension = 4032;
    PixelYDimension = 3024;
};
"{JFIF}" =     {
    DensityUnit = 0;
    JFIFVersion =         (
        1,
        0,
        1
    );
    XDensity = 72;
    YDensity = 72;
};
"{TIFF}" =     {
    Orientation = 6;
};
```

Where is original date and time, digitized date and time or GPS cordination. Because my image have this metaData.

My SWIFT code:

```
let TEST_IMAGE: String = "IMG_6489.JPG"
let beach: UIImage = UIImage(named: TEST_IMAGE)!
let imageData: Data = beach.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)!

let cgImgSource: CGImageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData as CFData, nil)!
let uti: CFString = CGImageSourceGetType(cgImgSource)!
let dataWithEXIF: NSMutableData = NSMutableData(data: imageData)
let destination: CGImageDestination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData((dataWithEXIF as 
CFMutableData), uti, 1, nil)!

let imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(cgImgSource, 0, nil)! as 
NSDictionary
let mutable: NSMutableDictionary = imageProperties.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableDictionary

print(mutable)
print(mutable[kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeOriginal])
```

Comment: I have also this issues

Comment: @ValdyB You said you tried my code in your question but obviously you didn't. OP: I tried your code in the playground and it didn't work for me either and the problem is you are loading the image via UIImage and jpegData. You need to use an URL and load the content of the file directly. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66910955/9223839) for an example. This will retain the metadata so you can access all the fields

Comment: But I think a little difficult use from URL because my goal pick from iOS photo library ant check metaData

Comment: Ok but going via UIImage and getting the data from `jpegData(...)` is probably the cause of this problem

Comment: Yap probablu UIImage remove all metaData and I don't know how to solve this :(

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I fix this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67441404/save-edited-image-metadata-in-swift but now I can't save....